# Constant id for all the items of a ListView making OnClick method useless

Tags: android, listview

I'm quite new to android and i'm facing some trouble with managing listviews...
I'm generating a ListView properly but all the items in it have the same id, so when I click on any of them, they all do the same thing (which is not what I expect of course...)

I'm loading data from XML URLs, parsing them with a SAX parser.
Here is my adapter. My "liste" contains 6 rows of 2 strings separated by "&&&".
I then display the listview with :

```
  zadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   setListAdapter(this.zadapter);
```

---

source below

---

```
class InfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private ArrayList<String> items;
  public InfoAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> items) {
   super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
   this.items = items;
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View v = convertView;
   if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
   }
   String liste = items.get(position);
   String[] info = liste.split("&&&");
   if (liste != null) {
    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
    TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
    if (tt != null) {
     tt.setText(info[0]);
    }
    if(bt != null){
     bt.setText(info[1]);
    }
    Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Debug position text"+tt.getId());
   }
   Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Debug position view"+v.getId());
   return v;
  }
 }
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your debug statement, you are having the id of the view which is an identifier and what I believe you want is the index.

To trigger an action that depends on the selected item,
you have to use the `setOnItemClickListener` method from the ListView and implement the `OnItemClickListener` interface.

The method 
`public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id)`
is the one you need. See the description of the method [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can request the listview for an index of the selected item and use that, in combination with your listadapter to figure out the actual data of the view.

Comment: That is what i'm trying to do, but the index appears to be the same for all items...

Comment: The adapter you implement has a method: getItemId(int position)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to extend from `BaseAdapter` (doesn't require much more work), as `ArrayAdapter<T>`'s internal list of objects is hidden from your subclass and so your overriden methods are using a completely different list of objects.

See the [ArrayAdapter source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) for more details, especially the `private List<T> mObjects` bit.

Comment: I'll have a look at that tomorrow.
Thx for the idea.